# Send Emails to people outside AD

Tags: 2013, workflow, email

Is there a way to send Emails from workflow to users outside the AD. For e.g. I want to send emails to xyz@yahoo.com from my workflow.

I'm using SharePoint 2013 on premise and 2010 workflows are not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Due to security enhancement in SharePoint 2013 workflows to enable the users to get approval from the administrators before sending emails to the external users.

there is a workaround for it, you have to work with user profile service.

read more over here: [SharePoint 2013 - Unable to send emails to external email addresses (SharePoint 2013 workflows)](http://blogs.technet.com/b/rajbugga/archive/2013/10/15/sharepoint-2013-unable-to-send-emails-to-external-email-addresses-sharepoint-2013-workflows.aspx)

One more thing, if you are using exchange them make sure SharePoint server should added into exchange relay

Comment: " workflows to enable the users to get approval from the administrators before sending emails" Can you put more line on this statement.